# Roundcube native pdf reader plugin for OpenBSD

Tags: email, openbsd

Anyone knows a working plugin which at least able to display inline PDF files:

The only one I found is 7 years old:
https://gitlab.awesome-it.de/kolab/roundcube-plugins/tree/feature_caldav/plugins/pdfviewer

Set that aside it would might even work but it uses mozillas/pdf.js which does not compile with Node 10 on OpenBSD anymore.

Is there any out of the box solutions for this? I want to avoid using the cloud office plugin which uses Google Docs/Office 365.

Comment: Why would you need to compile it? It's run in browser, not server side.

Comment: Perhaps [cloudview](https://github.com/jfcherng-roundcube/plugin-cloudview) would be an option. I think you can edit `config.inc.php` and remove Google and MS Office Web as defaults, or even edit `src/Helper/PluginConst.php` and remove them altogether. Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.